# Overlapping elements with forEachFeatureAtPixel function

Tags: javascript, angular, openlayers

I have an app using openlayers, on the map there are multiple features overlapping each other if the view is zoomed out. I used zIndex attribute to set them in required order.

I want to make a popup that displays name of the top element(by zIndex) but forEachFeatureAtPixel function returns some other. How can I make it to choose the top element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

I was returning only first element from forEachFeatureAtPixel like that

```
feature = event.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, (feat: any) => {
  return feat;
});
```

When I should do this like that

```
features = [];
event.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, (feat: any) => {
  features.push(feat);
});
```

I works now although I get some undefined element if there are at least 2 features for some unknown reason